# Add row value to previous row value and add this to next row value in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to create a new column where I add a row value to the one previous. For example, I want to create a new column "lane_deviation_additive" where I add lane_deviationROW1 + lane_deviationROW2, and then I want to add lane_deviationROW3 to that result, and then lane_deviationROW4 to that results etc.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
example <- structure(list(ppid_trialn = c("1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4", 
"1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4", "1_1_4"), lane_deviation = c(0, 
0.000155266125100885, 0.000155489294201173, 0.000155766010066695, 
0.000155765951852893, 0.000155069487777508, 0.000154819918395414, 
0.000156239855052866, 0.000155319064160215, 0.00015709614437562
)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(ppid_trialn = "1_1_4", .rows = list(
    1:10)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I feel like this is possible using dplyr using the lag function, but I'm unsure how I can also add the next row to the result of adding the previous rows. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please show your expected output for the given example.

Comment: Maybe you mean this? `cumsum(example$lane_deviation)` Sounds like you're looking for a cummulative sum of a column...

Comment: @MrFlick that's correct. Initially I thought about posting a solution with `... %>% group_by(ppid_trialn) %>% ...` as a bit more general, but I changed my mind without removing the package :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
    mutate(lane_deviation_additive = cumsum(lane_deviation))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 example[,"lane_deviation_additive"] <-cumsum(example$lane_deviation)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.